# how to use poi to find word2003`s table

Tags: apache-poi

i use org.apache.poi.poi version 3.17
i want to fine the inclined line in office word2003(doc)  tables

for example
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohjAE.png)

i used the XWPFTableRow function
cell.get(index).getCttc().getTcPr().getTcBorders();
to  find where is the line in word2007 version (docx)

my code like this :

````
Rang range = hwpf.getRange();
TableIterator iterator = new TableIterator(range);
while(iterator.hasNext())
{
 Table next = iterator.next();
 for(int i = 0; i<next.numRows();i++)
 {
  TableRow row = next.getRow(i);
  for(int j =0 ;j<row.numCells();j++)
  {
    TableCell cell = row.getCell(j);
    //now i cant find likeness function to find the line in doc 
  }
 }
}```

but i can`t find likeness function in HWPFDocument 
so i need your help 
thank you so much
````